# Create directory while upload using django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

After uploading a file from the UI, how to create the a new directory with the current timestamp in /opt/files/  and copy the uploaded zip file to this directory, and unzip the zip file in the new directory and maintain the new directory name in a variable

```
def upload_info(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file=request.FILES['file']
        dir = "/opt/files"
        file_name = "%s/%s" % (dir, file.name)
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        try:
            handle_uploaded_file( file_name , file )

def handle_uploaded_file(file_name,f):
    destination = open(file_name, 'wb+')
    for chunk in f.chunks():
        destination.write(chunk)
    destination.close()
    return
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Creating a directory can be achieved using Python's `os` module (see [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.mkdir)). For example:

```
import os
from datetime import datetime
dirname = datetime.now().strftime('%Y.%m.%d.%H.%M.%S') #2010.08.09.12.08.45 
os.mkdir(os.path.join('/opt/files', dirname))
```

You can use `os.rename` ([documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.rename)) to move the file as you choose (provided you have the necessary permissions). Unzipping can be done through the command line using [Subprocesses](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) or using a [Python module](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html) (Examples using `gzip` module can be found [here](http://docs.python.org/library/gzip.html#examples-of-usage)).

Comment: What if that directory already exists? Will it overwrite the existing one or just throw a "File exists" error?

Comment: @teewuane If it already exists, it will throw an error. [`os.makedirs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs) will create missing parent directories, and in Python 3.2, you can use `ok_exists=True` to avoid an error if the directory already exists.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function I use:

```
def makedirs(path):
    try:
        os.makedirs(path)
    except OSError as e:
        if e.errno == 17:
            # Dir already exists. No biggie.
            pass
```

Answer (score 0):

So, the correct answer for directory creation is:

If you want to create folders silently (if they don't exist):

```
import os
os.makedirs(exist_ok=True)
```

Throw an error if folder already exists:

```
import os
os.makedirs()
```